# JavaScript function for taking JSON data and formatting in to HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have written a JavaScript function that takes JSON encoded data and then, with conditionals, formats that data into a table.

I asked this question not so long ago but that was just a snippet of this:

[Better way to code these deeply nested / multiple if/else statements](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60596/better-way-to-code-these-deeply-nested-multiple-if-else-statements)

This is the full thing with all the structure and bells and whistles.  The code is heavily commented, so it should make sense.  I feel the structure of the code is easy to read and as it should be. Don't hold back on the criticism!

```
 $.getJSON("People.json",
                function(data) {
                    content = '<tr>';
                    content += '<tbody>';
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var Person = data[i];
                        var swipeStatus;
                        var HolidayType;
                        console.log(Person.IsNightShift);
                        /////////////////Placing the OP Colum no formatting needed//////////////
                        content += '<td>' + Person.Op + ' </td>';

                        // If statment to figue out which kind of holiday they are on if any ///      
                        if (Person.Shift == 281) {
                            HolidayType = 'OnHoliday';
                        } else if (Person.Shift == 282) {
                            HolidayType = 'HolidayAM';
                        } else if (Person.Shift == 283) {
                            HolidayType = 'HolidayPM';
                        } else {
                            HolidayType = null;
                        }

                        /////////////////The main logic for the Name colum//////////////////////
                        //Is the person on holiday?
                        if (HolidayType !== null) {
                            swipeStatus = "OnHoliday";
                            //Nope were they night shift and gone home?
                        } else if (Person.IsNightShift == true && Person.ON !== false) {
                            swipeStatus = "NightHome";
                            //Nope Are they day shift and gone home?
                        } else if (Person.OUT !== false) {
                            swipeStatus = "DayHome";
                            //Nope are they day-afternnon shift and gone home?
                        } else if (Person.DifHours > 1 && Person.ON === false) {
                            swipeStatus = "DayHome";
                            //Nope Have they been on dinner and come back? if so set to Lime
                        } else if (Person.ON !== false) {
                            swipeStatus = "backFromDinner";
                            //Nope are they still on dinner? if so set to Yellow
                        } else if (Person.OFF !== false) {
                            swipeStatus = "outForDinner";
                            //nope Did they clock in? if so set to green
                        } else if (Person.Clock !== false) {
                            swipeStatus = "inNormally";
                            // They never clocked in, Set to red!
                        } else {
                            swipeStatus = "defaultStatus";
                        }
                        //Display the name colum withthe correct formatting
                        content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + Person.Name + '</td>';

                        //This is the Logic for the Work hours start and end times colum mainily used to say what type of holiday 
                        //If the person is no on holiday then just display the infomation in plain text
                        if (Person.Clock !== false) {
                            swipeStatus = "Blank";
                            content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + Person.WorkHours + ' </td>';
                            content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + Person.Start + ' </td>';
                            content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + Person.End + ' </td>';
                            // IF the person is on a holiday then set the colum to purple and tell the user they are on holiday
                        } else if (Person.Shift == 281) {
                            swipeStatus = "OnHoliday";
                            content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + "Holiday" + ' </td>';
                            content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + "Holiday" + ' </td>';
                            content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + "Holiday" + ' </td>';
                            // IF the person is on a holiday then set the colum to purple and tell the user they are on holiday
                        } else if (Person.Shift == 282) {
                            swipeStatus = "OnHolidayAM";
                            content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + "Hol AM" + ' </td>';
                            content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + "Hol AM" + ' </td>';
                            content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + "Hol AM" + ' </td>';
                            // IF the person is on a holiday then set the colum to purple and tell the user they are on holiday
                        } else if (Person.Shift == 283) {
                            swipeStatus = "OnHolidayPM";
                            content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + "Hol PM" + ' </td>';
                            content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + "Hol PM" + ' </td>';
                            content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + "Hol PM" + ' </td>';
                            // IF the person is on a holiday then set the colum to purple and tell the user they are on holiday
                        } else {
                            swipeStatus = "Blank";
                            content += '<td -webkit-column-width: 100 px;>' + Person.WorkHours + ' </td>';
                            content += '<td>' + Person.Start + ' </td>';
                            content += '<td>' + Person.End + ' </td>';
                        }


                        ///////////////This is the main logic for the Clockin colum///////////////
                        // if the person has not clocked in set the visability to invisable
                        if (Person.Clock === false) {
                            swipeStatus = "NoClock";
                            // if the person is late by 10 mins set to cyan
                        } else if (Person.Late > 10) {
                            swipeStatus = "ClockEarly";
                            // if the person is early by 10 mins set to orange
                        } else if (Person.Late < -10) {
                            swipeStatus = "ClockLate";
                            //if they are ontime with +-10 mins set to lime 
                        } else {
                            swipeStatus = "ClockOntime";
                        }
                        //put the infomation in to colum with the formatting 
                        content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + Person.Clock + '</td>';


                        ///////////////This is the main logic for the OFF colum///////////////
                        //if the person has not swiped off set cell to hidden
                        if (Person.OFF === false) {
                            swipeStatus = "NoClock";
                            //else set to a misleading rule name (no css styling plain cell)
                        } else {
                            swipeStatus = "Blank";
                        }
                        content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + Person.OFF + '</td>';


                        ///////////////This is the main logic for the ON colum same as above with different info///////////////
                        if (Person.ON === false) {
                            swipeStatus = "NoClock";
                            // else set the cell to the same unstyled cell
                        } else {
                            swipeStatus = "Blank";
                        }
                        content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + Person.ON + '</td>';


                        // this if statment hides the pertentially undeeded could just put another logic block at the bottom to black every cell in each row if there is 
                        //no clock info insted of blanking each cell of the logic blocks 
                        if (Person.Clock === false) {
                            swipeStatus = "NoClock";
                            content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + Person.OFF + '</td>';
                            //If the person goes home with only have 2 out of the standard 4 swiped through the day and there second swipse is 10 mins less than there assgined home time set to Cyan
                        } else if (Person.DifHours > 1 && Person.ON === false && Person.HomeEarly > 10) {
                            swipeStatus = "ClockEarly";
                            content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + Person.OFF + '</td>';
                            //same as above but 10 mins or over home time
                        } else if (Person.DifHours > 1 && Person.ON === false && Person.HomeEarly < -10) {
                            swipeStatus = "ClockLate";
                            content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + Person.OFF + '</td>';
                            //same as above but with the 10 mins either side
                        } else if (Person.DifHours > 1 && Person.ON === false) {
                            swipeStatus = "ClockOntime";
                            content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + Person.OFF + '</td>';
                            //If the person is night shift and has clocked off at there off time with 10 mins either side set to green
                        } else if (Person.IsNightShift == true && Person.ON !== false && Person.HomeEarlyNight > -10 && Person.HomeEarlyNight < 10) {
                            swipeStatus = "ClockOntime";
                            content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + Person.ON + '</td>';
                            //If the person is night shift and has clocked off at there off time 10 mins early
                        } else if (Person.IsNightShift == true && Person.ON !== false && Person.HomeEarlyNight > 10 && Person.HomeEarlyNight < 1000) {
                            swipeStatus = "ClockEarly";
                            content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + Person.ON + '</td>';
                            //If the person is night shift and has clocked off at there off time 10 mins Late
                        } else if (Person.IsNightShift == true && Person.ON !== false && Person.HomeEarlyNight < -10) {
                            swipeStatus = "ClockLate";
                            content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + Person.ON + '</td>';
                        } else if (Person.OUT === false) {
                            swipeStatus = "NoClock";
                            content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + '</td>';
                            //if the person doesn't fit the critria above then they must have 4 swipes and a Person.Home time which is a value that shows how many mins thay are over or under there
                            //offical home times they are, the formatting is alittle stange but if it's > than 10 they have gone 10 miniets or over early
                        } else if (Person.Home > 10) {
                            swipeStatus = "ClockEarly";
                            content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + Person.OUT + '</td>';
                            //same as above but gone late
                        } else if (Person.Home < -10) {
                            swipeStatus = "ClockLate";
                            content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + Person.OUT + '</td>';
                            //if non of that is true they have been good people and gone when they should!
                        } else {
                            swipeStatus = "ClockOntime";
                            content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + Person.OUT + '</td>';
                        }

                        content += '</tr>';
                    }
                    ;
                    content += '</tbody>';
                    content += '<p>';
                    $(content).appendTo("tbody");
                });
```

Comment: One quick remark: The HTML structure you are generating is completely broken: You open a single `tr` (which instead should be inside the loop, one for each `Person`), you add a `tbody` inside of it, which is not allowed, and finally at the end you append everything **inside** every single already existing `tbody`.

Comment: And there is an extra `p` tag that is not allowed inside a table/tbody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally concatenating strings is very slow and memory hogging. Use an array and join it together at the end. E.g.:

```
var content = [];
content.push("<td>");
content.push(Person.Op);
content.push("</ td>");
return content.join("");
```

---

You assign `HolidayType` depending on `Person.Shift` but never use it, other than checking for `null`, but query `Person.Shift` again the same way later.

Other than that you could set `HolidayType` using an hash map instead:

```
var SHIFTS = {
  281: 'OnHoliday',
  282: 'HolidayAM',
  283: 'HolidayPM'
}

var holidayType = SHIFTS[Person.Shift] || "";
```

---

Why is the variable called `swipeStatus`? What does "swipe" mean in this context?

---

Use one string instead of unnecessarily concatenating here.

```
content += '<td class="' + swipeStatus + '">' + "Holiday" + ' </td>';
```

---

Generally helper function for the table cells would be useful. Something like:

```
function dataCell(value, class) {
   var dataCell = [];

   dataCell.push("<td");
   if (class) {
     dataCell.push(" class='" + class + "'");
   }
   dataCell.push(">");
   dataCell.push(value);
   dataCell.push("</td>");

   return dataCell.join("");
}
```

---

`<td -webkit-column-width: 100 px;>` => `<td style="-webkit-column-width: 100 px;">`

Moving it to the style sheet would be even better.

---

Finally:

- Consider using a JavaScript template engine instead if building the HTML yourself.
- Move more/most/all logic to the server.